# MySQL CASE statement do not work

Tags: mysql

Is there something wrong with my `CASE` statement ? If the first `WHEN` clause is valid then it breaks, right? Or I missunderstood the whole point. This is my query

```
SELECT `product`.* 
FROM `product` 
LEFT JOIN `productLang` 
ON `product`.`id` = `productLang`.`product_id`
WHERE (
    `product`.`active` = 1 
    AND (
        `productLang`.`title` LIKE '%a%' 
        OR `productLang`.`description` LIKE '%a%'
    ) 
AND 
    (
        CASE 
        WHEN `product`.`cat_id`<>0 THEN `product`.`cat_id`=367
        WHEN `product`.`parent`<>0 THEN `product`.`parent`=367
        WHEN `product`.`grand_parent`<>0 THEN `product`.`grand_parent`=367
        END
    )
)
AND (`language`='bg') GROUP BY `product`.`id`
```

If the first `WHEN` condition is `true` then it will check for `product.cat_id=367` and if the second one is `true` then `product.parent=367` and so on. I is right or I am in big mistake here? Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is not “checking” for anything - the CASE statement returns a value.

Comment: Please first of all properly describe what you want to _achieve_ here.

Comment: You are in a big mistake. That's not the way it works. If the first WHEN is true, then returns a value and so on

Comment: I have 3 columns. `cat_id`, `parent`, `grand_parent`. If the first one is equal to `0` than select the second one and so on. I think I described it below the code. Sorry if it is not clear enough. Thank you both of you. Will search for the right way.

Comment: Wrong use of your case when, you should do something like that : AND ( `product`.`cat_id`=367 OR  `product`.`parent`=367 OR `product`.`grand_parent`=367)

Comment: @toma-tomov The query in itself seems confusing. Consider my points: 1) `products` table will have unique items with `id`, than why `GROUP BY` clause? 2) In your `CASE` statement `WHEN` none of the condition gets satisfied, from `cat_id`, `parent`, `grand_parent`, you have not handled using `ELSE`?